# Probelm With Scanf, C Langugae

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, stdio

I Was Working On Small Program In **C Language**. It Should Get **How Many Hours User Has Worked In A Week(Input)** Then Display **Salary(output)** Based On It. Problem Is That I Want To Make Infinite Loop To Make Sure That User Write **Numbers Only** In Input Like This:

```
int hours;

// get input
while(1)
{
    printf("How Many Hours You Worked This Week: ");
    
    if(scanf("%u", &hours))
        break;
    else
        printf("oops, Write Integers Only not string or chars\n");
}
```

But Problem Is That When User Write Wrong Input **It Execute Else And Then Repeat Loop**, But
It Doesn't Stop To Ask For Input Again! It Just Keep Repeating.
I Think It Is Problem With **\n char** And **Scanf** (I Always Have Problem With This Func :)).
**I Will Be Happy If You Help!**

Comment: "Problem with scanf" is a truism.

Comment: If there is an invalid character in the input stream, `scanf` will not consume it.  Since you're in a loop, it will continue to try (and fail) to read that character.  As a simple hack, try `fprintf(stderr, "oops\n"); getchar();` to consume at least one character on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: `scanf` is terrible for reading in uncontrolled input (and arguably terrible in general). Input that is not matched remains in the input stream. Use something like `fgets` to consume the input and then `sscanf` to attempt to parse it.

Comment: The easy solution to this problem — this will sound like a terrible cop-out, but I mean it — is "don't worry about it".  Tell the users of your program that when they're supposed to type numeric input, they *must* type numeric input, and that if they don't, the program will misbehave.

Comment: Of course it's possible to write a program that enforces numeric input, that prints something like "please try again" when the user fails, but *it is not reasonable to build such a a program around `scanf`*.  `scanf` is simply not up to the job.